# Flutter/Riverpod - should I use a RiverPod StateNotifier Provider to represent form state

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I'm learning flutter and I was wondering how the state management works. At the moment I have a form in which I want to preview a selected image, selected country or a loader when submitted.
Not sure if the approach is correct though. I feel like this kind of state management should be done differently. Please, let me know if it's okay to use state management or if it's not, how should I approach such cases.

```
// Define a loader for the user profile update
final isLoadingProvider = StateProvider<bool>((ref) => false);
final selectedCountryProvider = StateProvider<String?>((ref) => null);
```

Let me share only the widgets I'm using the states on.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ref) {
    final isLoading = ref.watch(isLoadingProvider);
    final selectedCountry = ref.watch(selectedCountryProvider);
    ... next part of the code
```

```
// Inside column widget's childrens
if (isLoading) const CircularProgressIndicator(),
```

```
      TextFormField(
        initialValue: selectedCountry ?? userProfile.country,
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
          labelText: "Country",
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: textColor)),
          hintText: 'Select a country'),
        onTap: () => showCountryPicker(
          context: context,
          showPhoneCode: false,
          onSelect: (Country value) {
            ref.read(selectedCountryProvider.notifier).state = value.name;
          },
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Avoid legacy riverpod tools. In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).

Answer (score 1):

Riverpod suggests to [avoid using providers for local widget state](https://riverpod.dev/docs/essentials/do_dont#avoid-using-providers-for-local-widget-state). If there are multiple widgets in the same widget tree that need to access the state, you can put the state in the topmost widget (make it a state variable of a `StatefulWidget`'s `State`, or use [`useState`](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_hooks/latest/flutter_hooks/useState.html) from [flutter_hooks](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks)) and pass down the state through parameters.

If you really need shared state, then you can use [`Notifier`](https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/riverpod/Notifier-class.html) instead, since `StateProvider` is now [discouraged](https://riverpod.dev/docs/migration/from_state_notifier). The most basic example of using a `Notifier` for a shared state is shown in the homepage of [Riverpod docs](https://riverpod.dev/):

```dart
// A shared state that can be accessed by multiple widgets at the same time.
@riverpod
class Count extends _$Count {
  @override
  int build() => 0;

  void increment() => state++;
}
```

```
// Consumes the shared state and rebuild when it changes
class Title extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final count = ref.watch(countProvider);
    return Text('$count');
  }
}
```

If you don't want to use code generator, you can define the provider and the notifier like this:

```dart
final counterProvider = NotifierProvider<Counter, int>(Counter.new);

class Counter extends Notifier<int> {
  @override
  int build() => 0;

  void increment() => state++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  What I can't get around is. Why for such simple logic, like showing and hiding a loader or preview an image I should create separate classes then create methods and call those methods where I can just do: 
final isLoadingProvider = StateProvider<bool>((ref) => false);
final selectedCountryProvider = StateProvider<String?>((ref) => null);
Then if update is needed =>
1. ref.read(selectedCountryProvider.notifier).state = value.name;
2. ref.read(isLoading.notifier).state = true;

Is it really necessary to write so much code for such cases?

Comment: The reason is to discourage putting business logic on the UI side. Furthermore, an isLoading state should never go into a provider most of the time. Just make it a state variable and use setState as usual, as it's an ephemeral state (local widget state) that's only bound to a specific widget.

Answer (score 0):

Form state should *not* be put inside providers.

Form state is local to UI widgets and tightly coupled with navigation. For example, if you have a form that spans over multiple pages, if the user presses "back" at a step, this should likely reset currently visible fields.
Or a user may quit a form, and re-enter it again later. Again, it probably would be unexpected to have the previous form state preserved.

As such, using providers for form state is undesirable.

The recommended solution is to use plain StatefulWidgets. Or if you wish to be fancy, use [flutter_hooks](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks), which is typically combined with Riverpod for animations or forms.